# how to list images available in a public amazon ecr repo?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecr, amazon-ecr-public

i'd like use the aws cli to list images available here: https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs

when i try the following command:

```sh
aws ecr-public describe-image-tags --repository-name lambda/nodejs
```

i get this error:

```sh
User: arn:aws:sts::<my-session> is not authorized to perform: \
ecr-public:DescribeImageTags on resource: arn:aws:ecr-public::<my-account>:repository/lambda/nodejs
```

how do i specify the aws public repository, and not one of my own?

the [api docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecr-public/describe-image-tags.html) mention a `--registry-id` option, to supply an account ID, or if left blank *"..the default public registry is assumed"*, but it seems like my account info is still being inserted.

**Q:** can someone provide a working example of a command that lists each of (or the first pagination of) the tags in the *Image tags* panel of a repo in the [Amazon ECR Public Gallery](https://gallery.ecr.aws/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At time of writing, this can only be found by visiting the ECR Public gallery. There is no way to programmatically get a list of tags in ECR Public for a repository you haven't been explicitly granted API access to. Here's the relevant roadmap item https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1262

Answer (score 0):

Actually AWS CLI supports the `Public Repositories` you created, which are linked with your account. Like I created a repository named `randomname` and I was able to list images under that.

```sh
$ aws ecr-public describe-images --repository-name randomname
{
    "imageDetails": [...]
}
```

[Amazon ECR public registries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/public/public-registries.html)

> You can use your public registry to manage public image repositories consisting of Docker and Open Container Initiative (OCI) images. Each AWS account is provided with a default public and private Amazon ECR registry

To be more specific this part you see in the `AWS Console`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the tags listing API is now available in ECR Public: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1262